# Is there something better than Navicat in OSX?

Tags: macos, function, postgresql

I'm working with postgreSQL and developing a lot of PLPGSQL functions and procedures, and navigation is getting tedious and giving me headaches.

At database level (tables and such) it is fine but developing functions is a pain in the neck.

Comment: What is your specific frustration?  Is it a lack of cross-referencing or the like?  Or difficulty finding/selecting the function you want?

Comment: mostly lack of standard cross-referencing info when editing plpgsql, i ended building the querys into a separate query window and then copy/pasthe them later in the function . also i had visual impediments that makes that makes that really painfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation would be to look at Eclipse with the Toad Extensions (http://toadextensions.com/).  These support exploring the database, cross references, etc.  It is the most promising solution I have seen so far.

The one thing of course is that I am not sure how well the cross-platform solutions will look on a Mac but at some point if your frustrations are primarily functional, it is worth looking at.